# Token transfer from private network to public

Tags: quorum

I want to transfer my token from private network(quorum) to public network(ethereum), so I have burned the equal amount of tokens in quorum network and minted same amount of tokens in ethereum network. How could I know that these minted tokens came from quorum network. Is there any way to get that quorum block information from ethereum so that it could tell that these minted tokens came from quorum network ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ethereum blockchain is deterministic which means that it can only take in new information from transactions. So all data you want to use has to come in a transaction.

If you want you can use oracles to ask for any external data to be input into the blockchain. But oracles are typically centralized systems which means you have to trust the data the provide - this doesn't fit very well in the Ethereum's trustless nature.

In short, the answer is *no, you can't* include Quorum data inside Ethereum without a trusted third party (who includes the requested information inside the blockchain).

Comment: Is public ethereum network and quorum network interoperable? If so how can we connect both?

Comment: Not directly. There exist various bridges between them but they are at least partially centralized.